# Дискорд бот не реагирует на команды

Tags: javascript

[image: создал kick.js]

вообщем создал kick.js
туда скопировал код на кик

```
    // Import the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login("NTQ4ODgyMjk4NDQ4MjQ4ODY0.D1MAUA.DZp3zBweeRr1O8Lkn-x7Usth2dY");

/**
 * The ready event is vital, it means that only _after_ this will your bot start reacting to information
 * received from Discord
 */
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  // Ignore messages that aren't from a guild
  if (!message.guild) return;

  // If the message content starts with "!kick"
  if (message.content.startsWith('!kick')) {
    // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    // Read more about mentions over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      // If the member is in the guild
      if (member) {
        /**
         * Kick the member
         * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
         * There are big differences between a user and a member
         */
        member.kick('КИК ПО ПРИЧИНЕ ПАШОЛ НАХУЙ').then(() => {
          // We let the message author know we were able to kick the person
          message.reply(`папущена девуля ${user.tag}`);
        }).catch(err => {
          // An error happened
          // This is generally due to the bot not being able to kick the member,
          // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
          message.reply('не магу оформить кик солнышко ');
          // Log the error
          console.error(err);
        });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.reply('That user isn\'t in this guild!');
      }
    // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
    } else {
      message.reply('солнышко выбери глэка через @');
    }
  }
});

// Log our bot in using the token from https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me
client.login("ввел сюда свой код");
```

запустил все,но такова проблема что бот просто игнорит саму команду !kick,что делать?

Comment: сам решил спасибо.

Comment: Если уже решил, то поменяй токен, а то я с него сейчас сам зашёл (OldBot#4875)